# grep or writing for function which is better

Tags: c, linux, performance

I'm writing a program to copy from one drive to another drive for this i'm using 
`fdisk -l > fdiskOutput.txt` to check for whether device are present or not.

Then i'm writing the contents of the file into a buffer. And using `strstr` i'm checking for 
entries like `/dev/sda2` , `/dev/sdb1` and performing the copy operation.

Code is given below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    char * buff;
    int fileLength=0;
    system("fdisk -l > /fdiskinfo.txt");
    fileLength=GetFileLength("/fdiskinfo.txt");
    buff = malloc(fileLength);
    int fid = open("/fdiskinfo.txt",O_RDONLY);
    read(ifd,buff,fileLength+1);
    if((strstr(buff,"/dev/sda2") !=NULL && (strstr(buff,"/dev/sdb1") != NULL)
    {
         /*do copy operation */
    }
    else
    { 
        /* print something went wrong */
    }
        // method 2: using grep command
    {
    if(system("grep '/dev/sda2' /fdiskinfo.txt")==0 && system("grep /dev/sdb1 /fdiskinfo.txt");
    {
        /* copy operation */
    }
 }
```

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? If grep does what you want, there is no need to write your own version of it.

Comment: i don't like to use grep because it has many option and it will decrease the performance .

Comment: You're storing the output of a program spawned by `system` into a file and reading that file, and you're worried about the performance of `grep`!?

Answer (score 1):

Better way is  writing the code for checking. Because when you are calling the 
system function that time it create the new child process so it will consume the some memory
space for the new child process.

So until the child  ends it stop the execution of the working process. My choice is code
is better than using the system.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing that?  Just do:

```
char * target = argv[2]; /* or whichever arg you prefer */
dst = fopen( target, "w" );
if( dst == NULL ) {
  perror( target );
  exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}
```

If the partition doesn't exist, the fopen will fail and you'll get a nice error message explaining why.